# Check when number of associated records changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a `one to many relationship` and I want to trigger an event ( let's say send an email ) after the number of associated records change.

For example I want to let a user know when he has reached a milestone or something like that depending on this associated records number (maybe send an email after the followers records count reaches 100).

Should I do that with an observer, or a custom callback?

Comment: Are you really using Rails 2?

Comment: yep.. it's an old app which was never upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

Both would work, but I would use a callback - it would make an eventual upgrade to a newer Rails a bit easier.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? Like gimme a few guidelines?